# Outputs Information depending on the account logged

Tags: php, sql

I am creating a very basic SocialSite, you know like Facebook, Twitter, etc.
And I wonder how can I output the information depending on the account logged in the 'login.php'

I have tried using on my Profile.php

```
$result = $mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `UserName`='$user'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$fname = $row['FirstName'];
}
```

But it only shows a lot of unidentified index and variable error.
here's my login php in-case you are wondering.

```
require 'Connect.php';

$username = $_POST['inputUserName'];
$password = $_POST['inputPassword'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'user' WHERE 'UserName' = '$username'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if( mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 


    if($row['Password'] == $password){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
        header('Location:../links/profilePage.php');
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['err_msg'] = "invalid password";
        header('Location:../links/signIn.php'); 
    }
}
else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'user' WHERE `UserName` = '$username'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($res)){ 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 


        if($row['Password'] == $password){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location:../links/profilePage.php');
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['err_msg'] = "invalid password";
            header('Location:../links/signIn.php'); 
        }
    }
    else{ 
        $_SESSION['err_msg'] = "User does not exist";
        header('Location:../homePage.php');
    }
}
```

Help is always appreciated. thank you.

Edit: The whole ProfilePage

```
<html>

<?php
session_start();
require 'Connect.php';

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `UserName`='$user'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$fname = $row['FirstName'];
}
?>

<head>
    <!-- bootstrap plugin -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <!-- jquery plugin -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

    <!-- Site body css -->
    <style type="text/css">
        #SiteBody{
            width: 1100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>

<body>

    <div id="SiteBody">
    <center>

    <div class="hero-unit">
        <!-- Start header -->
        <img src="../images/logo.png"/>
        <!-- End header -->
            </center>


    <!--Header Bar!-->
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a class="brand">User Profile</a>

                    <!--Nav bar items!-->
                    <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
                        Search: <input id="search" name="search" type="search" placeholder="search for friends" class="input-medium"> &nbsp;
                        <a href="../links/addrequesters.php" class="navbar-link"> Home </a> &nbsp;
                        <a href="../links/settings.php" class="navbar-link"> Settings</a> &nbsp;
                        <a href="../php/logout.php" class="navbar-link">Sign-Out</a> &nbsp;
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Header Bar END !-->

    <br>
    <!--icon-->
    <div class="well span2" style="background-color:white; height: 200px; width: 135px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: white;" >
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <img src="../images/icon.png" alt="displaypic" style="height:200px; width:300px;">
                <p style = "text-align: center">

                </p>

            </ul>
        </div>


    <!-- Post Status -->        
    <!-- <div class="row-fluid" style="padding:1px;"> -->
        <div class="well span2" style="background-color:#4CBB17; height: 200px; width: 820px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: black;" >
            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                <strong> *SLIDE SHOW* </strong>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Basic Information -->
        <!-- <div class="row-fluid" > -->
        <div class="well span2" style="font-size: 25; background-color:#4DBD33; height:300px; width:620px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: black; " >
            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                <strong><u>Basic Information</u></strong>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
                        Name:<?php echo '$fname' ?>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        Gender:
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        Birthday:
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        Address:
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        Email:
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        Contact number:
                        <br>
                        <br>
            </ul>
        </div>

<!-- Display Picture -->
    <!-- <div class="row-fluid" style="padding:1px;"> -->
        <div class="well span2" style="background-color:#55AE3A; height: 300px; width: 335px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: black; " >

            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                <img src="../images/def.png" alt="displaypic" style="height:250px; width:285px; border:10px ridge; border-color:green; margin-top: 10px;">
                <p style = "text-align: center">
                    (User Name) <br>
                </p>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--work and edu boutton-->
    <div class="well span2" style="background-color:#93DB70; height: 250px; width: 280px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: black; " >

            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                <img src="../images/button1.png" alt="displaypic" style="height:250px; width:285px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <p style = "text-align: center">

                </p>

            </ul>
        </div>
            <!--hobbies and interests boutton-->
    <div class="well span2" style="background-color:#4CBB17; height: 250px; width: 280px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: black; " >

            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                <img src="../images/button2.png" alt="displaypic" style="height:250px; width:285px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <p style = "text-align: center">

                </p>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--upload boutton-->
    <div class="well span2" style="background-color:#93DB70; height: 250px; width: 335px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: black; " >

            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                <img src="../images/button3.png" alt="displaypic" style="height:250px; width:285px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <p style = "text-align: center">

                </p>

            </ul>
        </div>
<!-- Friends List -->
<!-- <div class="row-fluid"style="padding:1px;"> -->
        <div class="well span2" style="background-color:#4DBD33; height: 250px; width: 620px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: black;">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                <strong>Friends List</strong>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--view boutton-->
    <div class="well span2" style="background-color:#55AE3A; height: 250px; width: 335px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: black; " >

            <ul class="nav nav-list">

                <img src="../images/button4.png" alt="displaypic" style="height:250px; width:285px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <p style = "text-align: center">

                </p>

            </ul>
        </div>

    <div class="well span2" style="background-color:black; height: 2px; width: 1015px; border: 5px rigid; border-color: black; " >

            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <p style = "text-align: center" class="navbar-link">
                (c) Cabreros.Parman.Victory.Ylanan.
                </p>

            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: May it be the variable is wrong? you define `$username` in the second snippet and use `$user` in the first

Comment: Oh. I forgot to include. but it has
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']); at the first snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `UserName`='$user'");
```

Try removing the $ sign before the function mysql_query (i assume you mean the function)?

Some other tips: You should never ever pass user input values to your sql query to prevent the risk of SQL Injections. You have some code duplication here (and you do the same sql query twice, why?), maybe you should rethink your code architecture and use classes/functions.

It seems you save the passwords of your users in plain text? You should at least hash these passwords for security reasons.

Comment: Well the "$" worked.
Now I have this <?php echo '$fname' ?> but it only shows the keyword fname.
and then I have this Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\SN\SocialNetworking\links\profilePage.php on line 7

Comment: You should post the complete code of your profilePage.php, there aren't 7 lines in your snippet ;)

Comment: @Florian, since you are giving some good advices, maybe add to your answer that the mysql extension is deprecated and shall not be used anymore :)

Comment: @janatuerlich: Yep, you're right, forgot that, thanks :D

Comment: echo '$fname" -> remove the " before and after the variable, now it's just a text that will be outputted, not the value of the variable. To your undefined index: You should simply check, if a key exists in an array before accessing it: $username = isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? $_POST['username'] : '';

Comment: @Florian I have tried using isset. but seems nothing change. or I'm doing it wrong? Can you please explain further to me on what should I be doing?

Comment: Maybe you have no postdata with key username? In your login php file you're using inputUserName.

Comment: Changing it to inputUserName worked. Thank you so much @Florian.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us what errors you are getting.  I can suggest that one of the values does not exist such as

```
$_POST['inputUserName'];
$_POST['inputPassword'];
$row['Password']
```

You can use isset to see if it has a value

```
if (isset($_POST['inputUserName'])
  $username = $_POST['inputUserName'];
else
  $username = '';
```

Comment: The errors showing is

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\SN\SocialNetworking\links\profilePage.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined variable: mysql_query in C:\xampp\htdocs\SN\SocialNetworking\links\profilePage.php on line 9

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\SN\SocialNetworking\links\profilePage.php on line 9